# Rails 5 rename single resource route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to create a separate :show route, to use route globbing on the `:id` parameter. For this, I created a resource route without the show route and also a separate show route:

```
resource :test, except: [:show]
get 'test/*id', to: 'test#show', as: :test
```

the problem is that I receive the error: `You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as`option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.`

If I remove `as: :test` it works. `rails routes` shows:

```
    tests POST   /tests(.:format)
 new_test GET    /tests/new(.:format)
edit_test GET    /tests/:id/edit(.:format)
     test PATCH  /tests/:id(.:format)     <-- WHY??
          DELETE /tests/:id(.:format)
          GET    /tests/*id(.:format)
```

as you can see, `resources` renamed the `PATCH` route to `:test`. If I remove that route, the `DELETE` route is named `test`, and so on. How can I stop `resources` from using the `test` route name specifically? I cannot move my globbing route above the `resource` block obviously because then all other routes are globbed too.

What I want:

```
    tests POST   /tests(.:format)
 new_test GET    /tests/new(.:format)
edit_test GET    /tests/:id/edit(.:format)
          PATCH  /tests/:id(.:format)
          DELETE /tests/:id(.:format)
     test GET    /tests/*id(.:format)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem, but if you look on Rails Guides "Singular Resources" you can see:

```
Path      Controller      #Action           Used for
GET       /geocoder/new   geocoders#new     return an HTML form for creating the geocoder
POST      /geocoder       geocoders#create  create the new geocoder
GET       /geocoder       geocoders#show    display the one and only geocoder resource
GET       /geocoder/edit  geocoders#edit    return an HTML form for editing the geocoder
PATCH/PUT /geocoder       geocoders#update  update the one and only geocoder resource
DELETE    /geocoder       geocoders#destroy delete the geocoder resource
```

show, create, update and destroy use the same route but with different HTTP verbs. And in your case, `test` wrote with PATCH verb, because this verb earlier in the table, empty name means that it uses the same name as upper line.

Comment: So if it is allowed to use the same route name on routes with different verbs, why do I get this error? There is no other route named `test` with the  `GET` verb.

Comment: I accept this answer as correct because I did not know that the path name is used for multiple verbs at the same time. This way, I do not need to name my route `as: :test`, because it is already named test.

Comment: @EikeCochu what are you doing when you get this error? How are you try to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses the same prefix (say, in your case "test") for all those four routes[show(GET), update(PUT/PATCH), destroy(DELETE)] and it recognises the different routes with the HTTP Verbs.

Comment: I see. I thought empty route name means no route name, not the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
 test PATCH  /tests/:id(.:format)     <-- WHY??
      DELETE /tests/:id(.:format)
      GET    /tests/*id(.:format)
```

1. Patch is for your Update method routes.
2. Delete is for destroy method route.
3. that add by your custom route generated by `get 'test/*id', to: 'test#show', as: :test`

So, here you can make your show route with different alias. Ex like using  `as :show_test`